# Can a celery worker do more than one thing at a time?

Tags: python, celery

If I have a celery task such as the following:

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.webrequest')
def webrequest(*args):
    try:
        webrequest = requests.get('{0}'.format(args[0]), auth=(args[1], args[2]), verify=False, timeout=240)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        webrequest='cant talk to server'
    return webrequest
```

and a celery worker with only one core, so only 1 worker thread.  Is there a way and how would you have that worker perform two or more of these tasks at once?

Currently I am executing the working like so:

```
celery -A app.celery worker -l DEBUG
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that's possible. Why don't you just launch more than one worker?

See: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html 

celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h

Answer (score 0):

When I call it with the concurrency (thanks Ale) it allows me to have more threads than cpu's.

```
celery -A app.celery worker -c 30 -l DEBUG
```

Comment: Keep in mind that simply increasing the concurrency to a large value doesn't automatically improve the throughput. From personal experience, I've not seen improvement in the throughput after increasing concurrency beyond 5 when dealing with high volumes of tasks. This was a VERY beefy server. So I'm sure system resources was not a constraint. I strongly suspect that disk I/O because of logging may have been a bottleneck. But I don't have anything to back up that claim.